# Bank note program

Tags: c++

I am solving a [following programming problem](http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1018_en.html):

> **URI Online Judge | 1018 - Banknotes**
>
> *In this problem you have to read an integer number and calculate the smallest possible number of notes in which the value may be decomposed. The notes are of 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2 e 1. Print the value read and the list of notes.*
>
> **Input**
>
> The input file contain an integer number N (0 < N < 1000000).
>
> **Output**
>
> Print the minimum quantity of necessary banknotes, like as the given example.

I've tried a following solution:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool NTrue(int n);
void HowMany(int x, int BankNote);

int main(int argc, char ** argv) { 
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int BankNote = 100;
    if (NTrue(N)) { 
        while (BankNote != 0) { 
            if (BankNote == 25)
                BankNote = 20;  
            HowMany(N, BankNote); 
            N = N % BankNote;
            BankNote = BankNote / 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool NTrue(int n) {
    if (0 < n && n <= pow(10, 6))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void HowMany(int x, int BankNote) {
    int result = x / BankNote;
    float BN = BankNote;
    cout << result << " nota(s) de R$ " << fixed << setprecision(2) << BN << endl;
}
```

I'm not getting the desired result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At this time your question is not intelligible. Please reformat it.

Comment: It's very difficult to discern the question here.

Comment: You better paste the code again, check http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, the guide [ask] is also useful.

Comment: sorry i will give it another try first time post on this site

Comment: @H.Scorpe - I did my best to tidy up your example code formatting

Comment: @TimBergel i re-format as u said

Comment: @Tim I've tidied it up even more, should be manageable now, I think.

Comment: @KarolPiczak Thank you - much neater than I achieved - when I pressed tab my browser jumped out of the edit box (as it would) - I know this isn't the place to ask abhout this but is there a special trick to get the edit to accept tab characters?

Comment: @Tim I generally resort to `Ctrl+V`'ing 4 spaces after I've typed them once and copied them. (If you are on Linux, you can also simply _select_ 4 spaces (without explicitly copying them), then _middle mouse click_ wherever you want to insert them. Clumsy, but workable enough.

Comment: I'm not sure. I've just copy-pasted into an IDE editor. Faster than trying to find a way around those tabs.

Comment: @H.Scorpe - back to the actual question. What you are doing wrong is not running your code in a debugger, if you did that you could step through the code, watching what the if statements do and what values are in the various variables and pretty soon you will find the place where it is not doing what you expect and you can fix that. Then repeat until it works. If you get stuck, come back here and explain exactly where the problem is, what the variable values are and so forth and we will do our best to help.

Comment: well sir i tried and already debug the program the funny thing it runs just ok and it

Answer (score 1):

I see that the output has to have a peculiar format, writing `1,00` instead of `1`. Here the comma character is supposed to be a decimal floating-point separator.

I guess that when the online judge runs your program, it gets `1.00` instead. The character used for fractions depends on the locale; the online judge might be using a different locale, so it uses the dot character (`.`) as separator.

Try printing the `.00` part explicitly:

```
void HowMany(int x, int BankNote) {
    int result = x / BankNote;
    cout << result << " nota(s) de R$ " << result << ",00" << endl;
}
```

Of course, this is just a guess.

Comment: Probably a most reasonable explanation to this problem.

Comment: ya that was it even i am sure this is was my first answer and i change it after 
i will try it again as soon the site work ... 
thnx for u r help :D

Comment: i tried but the same :( 
i will ask our supervisor in the morning and keep u posted

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int nargc, char* argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  int arr[] = {100,50,20,10,5,2,1};
  std::vector<int> notes (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

  std::cout << n << std::endl;
  for( int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++ ) {
    int b = n/notes[i];
    if ( b > 0 ) { std::cout << b << " " << notes[i] << " bills " << std::endl; }
    n = n%notes[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```